# Water main pipe configuration?

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture

I am redoing the water lines in my home with PEX-A and am starting my upgrades at the home main gate-valve. I am wondering what this added capped down pipe is for and if it is integral to the configuration?

Any examples of a good configuration and/or terms I can google are most welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely to be able to drain the system - usually fitted at the lowest point.

Still fitted on some systems as one is on mine (in Switzerland), however many plumbers put isolation valves close to each device, like boilers, as isolation valves are so cheap now.